# CORS Origin set incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, cors, browser-security

1. I have a JavaScript application let's say that it is deployed on `portal.example.com`.
2. That includes a `<script>` tag that loads source that is served from `assets.example.com`.
3. That JavaScript file makes an HTTP request to an API on `admin.example.com`

This API request is erroring due to CORS pre-flight failing.

```
Failed to load http://admin.example.com/v0/user/navigation: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://portal.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The actual `OPTIONS` request is as below

```
OPTIONS /v0/user/navigation HTTP/1.1
Host: admin.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://portal.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,x-correlation-id,x-user-domain
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8
```

The actual `OPTIONS` response is as below

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Allow: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,x-correlation-id,x-user-domain
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://portal.example.com
Vary: Origin
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2018 12:12:19 GMT
Set-Cookie: 97d2c19dadc3933a73dce9bec0748df1=5a15895c5e0f5b526c177132cb4aa666; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-control: private
X-RBT-SCAR: 10.127.48.7:777511903:1000
```

I think the issue is because the request is actually coming from a script served from `assets.example.com` is making the request. So I should be returning `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://assets.example.com` in the `OPTIONS` response. However, I have followed the advice of [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header).

> The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header indicates whether a resource can be shared based by returning the value of the Origin request header, "*", or "null" in the response.

So am I misunderstanding CORS, or is the browser sending the `Origin` of the main executing URL and not the URL of the script making the request?

**UPDATED**

GET response

```
HTTP/1.1 200
X-Correlation-Id: 8978b245-081a-4c4a-b4c9-73f2920ab55c
Content-Type: application/vnd.example+json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2018 13:22:39 GMT
Set-Cookie: 97d2c19dadc3933a73dce9bec0748df1=dc4e3543c3071d752959e7176c5e4d29; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-control: private
X-RBT-SCAR: 10.127.48.7:778160108:2000
```

Comment: Can you please provide the headers of the `GET` response?

Comment: Your setup looks correct. What I'm about to suggest is going to be a stretch. On your server side where you setup CORS, first make sure that the spelling for the origin is correct. If it is, then take `http://portal.example.com` and delete the entire string (and the first characters before and after it) then re-type it in manually. I've seen instances where people copy and pasted some text that included some special unicode character that went undetected and caused some havoc.

Comment: @alex-rokabilis I have updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
That means that 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is missing, not that your domain is not allowed.

If you didn't have permission, you would see something like

`The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://www.example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.`

So, to solve your problem you need to configure your `GET` response to provide the necessary CORS headers as well as the `OPTIONS` response.

In your edited question the `GET` response headers doesn't provide anything for the  `Access-Control-*` so that's why you get the error!

Answer (score 1):

Your CORS preflight is **not** failing - you're getting a 200 response and all the required CORS response headers...

However, you're not returning any of the CORS response headers in the GET response - **that** is what's failing. At a minimum, you need to return a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header which matches the one returned in the OPTIONS response.

So just include this in your GET response and you'll be fine:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://portal.example.com
```

Finally, the `Origin` request header is added by the browser, and trust me - it's correct. But it really doesn't matter **what** value is sent, since all that is required is that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header **matches** the Origin request header (either by having a value of '*' or exactly matching the Origin value).